# Receiving a 200 status code instead of a 201

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm sending a simple ajax call to an api that will store the email / url I send it.

```js
const emailAnswer = this.state.emailAnswer;
const emailText = `${emailAnswer}`;
const fullurl = window.location.href;
const fullurlText = `${fullurl}`;
console.log(fullurlText);

$.ajax({
  url: '/email',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    email: emailText,
    url: fullurlText
  },
  statusCode: {
    200: function() {
      console.log('you got a 200');
    },
    201: function() {
      console.log('saved');
    },
    400: function() {
      console.log('email not posted');
    }
  },

}).done(function() {
  console.log('done');
});
```

I'm getting a 200 status code back when I submit this information to the api instead of a 201 status code.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that on your backend that the status code to be sent back is for sure supposed to be 200?

i.e. res.status(200).send('stuff')

Comment: Checked with the backend. 200 should be fine for our purposes.